# Grails: Alternate syntax to dynamically put properties into ConfigurationHolder.config

Tags: java, grails, groovy

So I am trying to write a function that will essentially loop through a list of strings (config keys) and put the associated value (from a form) into the `ConfigurationHolder.config` object. This is to allow an admin user to modify configuration values through a form.

I would rather not have to hardcode all of the properties like so:

```
config.my.first.property="foo"
config.my.second.property="bar"
config.etc="baz"
```

What I have been trying to do is something along the lines of:

```
String key = "my.first.property"
Object value = FOO
config.putAt(key, value)
```

But when I request the value later on using

```
config.my.first.property
```

The value is not set to the updated value.

Is there any way to do what I am describing or must I hardcode each property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to split up the keys on "`.`" and drill down through the levels yourself.  Fortunately this is very easy with judicious use of Groovy's array slicing and the `inject` method - this will work for any key (apart from pathological cases like the empty string or a key containing two consecutive dots):

```
String key = "my.first.property"
Object value = FOO

// split the key into its components
def keyParts = key.split(/\./)
// do config.my.first (i.e. up to the last-but-one component) and then set
// "property" (the last component) on the resulting ConfigObject
keyParts[0..<(keyParts.size() - 1)].inject(config) {
  conf, k -> conf."${k}"
}."${keyParts[-1]}" = value
```